# 2d grid how to find indices given node number

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, matrix

I created a 2d grid of divs with ids equal to the loop counter iteration. When I click a div I want to use its id to determine its position on the grid. So if I have a 4x4 grid and want the indices of the div with id=8 then the function would return 3,1 third row first column. How do you write a function given the grid size and block number, then return its coordinates (row and column)

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const N = 16;
var blocks = new Array(N);
function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c);
    cell.setAttribute("id",c);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  }


for (let i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
  blocks[i] = new Array(N);
}
  let count = 0;
  for(let x=0; x<=15; x++){
   for(let y=0; y<=15; y++){
    blocks[x][y] = count;
    count++;
  }
  //
  for(let x=0; x<=15; x++){
   for(let y=0; y<=15; y++){
    console.log(blocks[x][y]);
  }
}

}
}
makeRows(N, N);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
    <script src="astar.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to deal with this is to instead of storing them in a 2D array, store them in one long array so you can access them immediately just by the ID -- assuming the ID matches the index in the array

Then you want two functions: to turn an `ID` into an `X,Y`, and to turn an `X,Y` into an ID

```
const width = 12

const positionToIndex = (x, y) => (y * width) + x

const indexToPosition = (index) => ({
  x: index % width,
  y: Math.floor(index / width)
})
```

This assumes the top left is (0,0) and the initial index is 0. Then you would just initialize it as a regular flat array, and use `indextoPosition()` to find the x,y position

```
// Initialize
for (var i = 0; i < width*height; i++) {
  const position = indexToPosition(i)
  blocks[i] = new Cell(position.x, position.y)
}

// When cell is clicked
cell.onclick = (id) => {
  const {x, y} = indextoposition(id)
}
```